# Getting error "Fully Shadowed APK" while releasing apk from Beta to Production

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an existing app on the PlayStore. I am releasing new version from beta to production. However, I am not able to publish the app due to "Fully Shadowed APK" error.

[image: Error from Console]

Comment: Same issue with me.

Comment: got any solution

Comment: No I haven't got any solution...